# Why is there a negative value on the scada when the analog input wire is disconnected from a field instrument?

Tags: analog, plc, transducer, rtd, flow-sensor

I'm an apprentice electrician at an fmcg company.

I've been seeing a trend recently,  at the plant, where the scada actually reads a negative value instead of zero when a field device such as a current transducer or RTD fails, ie the feedback wire going back to the plc analog input card is discontinuous.

Should this value not be zero?

Moreover, a Flowmeter eprom was recently damaged due to an unexpected current surge so the Flowmeter reads 0g/h even when there's flow going through. This value was - 500g/h (negative 500) on the scada... 
 I mean,  if the Flowmeter or any other instrument isn't sending any electrical signals back to the plc, why does it not read a zero value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small negative values close to zero are essentially noise in the absence of a signal.  Larger negative values may arise if the plc has been calibrated with a gain and offset for that input.  If the offset would be negative then with a zero signal the calibration would return a negative value.

Answer (score 2):

It's common in control system design to want to indicate a faulty sensor in a positive (unmistakable) manner. In an analog system the only way to do that is to send a signal that's well out of the normal range of measurement. An input of zero (faulty sensor) could otherwise be confused with a valid input.

In the case of temperature transmitters used in heating applications, for example, we usually send a signal that is over-range high, so that the heat will shut off. In some applications you want the opposite.

Also it might be worth noting that in a system with 4-20mA transmitters, an open wire will represent an input of -25% of full scale for a zero-based signal. So if 4mA = 0°C and 20mA is 100°C then open (0mA) is -25°C.

Answer (score 0):

High impedance inputs are prone to EMI.

Current transducers 4~20mA at 0mA may not read 0 so your reading indicates an open fault.

I wonder if a sensor short circuit would be any different.

I don't see any reason why a flowmeter EPROM fault should affect a current transducer or an RTD.

Comment: the EPROM,  CT and RTD are all from separate faults that indicated similar negative readings on the scada. It was through these that I was able to pick out the trend